# Read a text file on server side which is sent from client side using C

Tags: c, sockets, server-side, serversocket

I want to send one text file from client side and want to read the text file on the server side and want to display the texts on the server terminal screen. I have successfully written code for both server and multiple client. I have also sent a text file from client to server side. But now I want to know how to modify the text file and send it and read the text file on server end which is sent from the client side. My server and client code is given below together:

**Server and Client Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define filename "//home//myname//Documents//folder1//folder2//input.txt"

#define MAX_CLIENTS 5


//the thread function
void *new_connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

    //client variables
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char buffer[256], server_reply[2000];
    int len;

    //server variables
    int socket_desc , client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t c = sizeof(client);


    //check if the the command contain less than two arguments
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("use either: %s <server/client>\n", argv[0]);
    }

    // If the command contains minumum 2 arguments
    else{


        // If argv is client then execute the client code
        if(strcmp("client",argv[1]) == 0)
        {
            /****************/// Client code here **********************************************************************
            //Create socket
            sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
            if (sock == -1)
            {
                printf("Could not create socket");
            }
            puts("Socket created");

            server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
            server.sin_family = AF_INET;
            server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );


            //Connect to remote server
            if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
            {
                perror("connect failed. Error");
                return 1;
            }

            puts("Connected\n");


            //keep communicating with server
            /* Time to send the file */

            /******************************************************/
            FILE *pf;
            int fsize;

            pf = fopen(filename, "rb");
            if (pf == NULL)
            {
                printf("File not found!\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Found file %s\n", filename);

                fseek(pf, 0, SEEK_END);
                fsize = ftell(pf);
                rewind(pf);

                printf("File contains %ld bytes!\n", fsize);
                printf("Sending the file now\n");
            }

            while (1)
            {
                // Read data into buffer.  We may not have enough to fill up buffer, so we
                // store how many bytes were actually read in bytes_read.
                int bytes_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, pf);
                if (bytes_read == 0) // We're done reading from the file
                    break;

                if (bytes_read < 0)
                {
                    error("ERROR reading from file\n");
                }

                while (bytes_read > 0)
                {
                    int bytes_written = write(sock, buffer, bytes_read);
                    if (bytes_written <= 0)
                    {
                        error("ERROR writing to socket\n");
                    }

                }
            }

            printf("Done Sending the File!\n");
            printf("Now Closing Connection.\n");

            /*********************************************************************************/

            close(sock);

        }

        /****************/// Server code here **********************************************************************
        // If argv is server then execute the server code
        if(strcmp("server", argv[1]) == 0 )
        {
            //Create socket
            socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
            if (socket_desc == -1)
            {
                printf("Could not create socket");
            }

            //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
            server.sin_family = AF_INET;
            server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
            server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );
            bzero (&server.sin_zero, 8);

            //Bind
            if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
            {
                //print the error message
                perror("bind failed. Error");
                return 1;
            }

            //Listen
            listen(socket_desc , MAX_CLIENTS);

            //Accept and incoming connection
            printf("Waiting for incoming connections\n");

            c = sizeof(client);
            while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) )
            {
                printf("Connection accepted\n");
                pthread_t thread_id;

                if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  new_connection_handler , (void*) (intptr_t)client_sock) < 0)
                {
                    perror("could not create thread");
                    return 1;
                }

                printf("Handler assigned\n");
            }


            if (client_sock < 0)
            {
                perror("accept failed");
                return 1;
            }
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}


void *new_connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = (intptr_t)socket_desc;
    int read_size = 0;
    char client_message[2000];

    //PROBLEM **read the text file sent from client side and display the text on screen**
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , sizeof(client_message) , 0)) > 0 )
    printf("Read Text: %.*s", read_size, client_message);

if(read_size == 0)
{
    printf("Client disconnected\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
else if(read_size == -1)
{
    perror("recv failed");
}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have no code that attempts to read the socket on the server side, so code *something* first. And btw, `while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) )` is wrong. The function `accept()` returns `-1` on failure, which will allow your while-loop bobby entrance with an invalid socket descriptor.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am not sure how to do it. Do I need to use recv ?

Comment: That would be a good place to start.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have tried but not successful.

Comment: @wildplasser your first sentence is not correct. The OP is purposely passing the descriptor as an `intptr_t`, storable-compatible per the standard with `void*` by-value, The extraction of that value in the thread proc is, in fact, correctly done. A dereference would be UB.

Comment: You are correct. I did not scroll to the right, and had not expected that someone would cast an int to a (void*)

Comment: But of course it is caused by the value being updated and reused after the thread starts. Call by reference would indeed cause problems in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had done some mistakes in your code.

```
int bytes_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1 ,pf);
```

This statement is wrong, when you print the `bytes_read` value it print 1 has a result.If you pass this to next while it will print the h repeatedly.

Use this below statement instead of that fread:

```
int bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pf);
```

This statement only returns the correct readed value.

```
while (bytes_read > 0)
{
   int bytes_written = write(sock, buffer, bytes_read);
   if (bytes_written <= 0)
   {
        error("ERROR writing to socket\n");
   }
}
```

In this part of the code your program writing the readed content again and again into the socket without break, so the server is print the text without break.

So use this statement after the write() `bytes_read=bytes_read-bytes_written;` if the read buffer is fully written in your socket it break the statement.

And one more thing is always try to use long data type, when you are trying to use file, because int has lower range compared to long.

**UPDATE:** 
Put the `fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pf);` and try it. It will work.

---

You can use open() or fopen().

```
fd=open("filename",O_RDWR);
```

fd - returns descriptor of the opened file.
O_RDWR - which is used to open file for read and write, you must include fcntl.h.

```
fp=fopen("filename","r+");
```

fp - File pointer.
rw - Opened file for both read and write.

**File content:**

```
Chandru
ttttt.
```

**After replace:**

```
Stackoverflowt.
```

Here the content is big so the content is overwritten in the another line.
To avoid that you need to write the changed content in another file.
Writing in another file would be easy to append the text in the line end.

Comment: I am unable to read the text from the server side. I cannot display the text which is written in the text file on server end. Do you have any solution for that. Please ...

Comment: do you have any idea about how to modify the text file and send it to server?

Comment: Please update in your question, what is the  content and how to modify it in the file.

Comment: I want to 1. replace the text and 2. add some extra text to the file

Comment: Can you show the sample content of the file, and show how to modify that in file?

Comment: In my file suppose it is written "Chandru" and I want to replace it with "Stackoverflow" (so when I read it in the server end , i read like "Stackoverflow") and suppose in my file it is written "Chandru" and I want to add "Stackoverflow" (so when i read it in the server end I read it like "Chandru Stackoverflow". Hope this makes sense.)

Comment: I am sorry, but where I need to use fd=open("filename",O_RDWR);and where I am writing Stackoverflow? I know this is simple question but I am new to this so please explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57264/discussion-between-chandru-and-user3751012).